Patric Collins' Stable Coin project testRevertsIfTransferFromFails calls vm.prank(msg.sender)
I'm following Patric Collin's stable coin course. testRevertsIfTransferFromFails
        address owner = msg.sender;
        vm.prank(owner);


The line sets msg.sender to msg.sender with vm.prank it doesn't make any sense to me. However if I remove the line the test fails with following error message.
Can anyone explain what vm.prank(owner) is called?
Thanks
➜  foundry-defi-stablecoin-f23-tt git:(main) ✗ forge test --match-test testRevertsIfTransferFromFails -vvvv
[⠒] Compiling...
[⠃] Compiling 1 files with 0.8.21
[⠊] Solc 0.8.21 finished in 1.78s
Compiler run successful with warnings:
Warning (2072): Unused local variable.
  --> test/unit/DscEngineTest.t.sol:77:9:
   |
77 |         DscEngine _dscEngine = new DscEngine(tokens, priceFeeds, address(dsc));
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Warning (2072): Unused local variable.
   --> test/unit/DscEngineTest.t.sol:106:9:
    |
106 |         address owner = msg.sender;
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^


Ran 1 test for test/unit/DscEngineTest.t.sol:DscEngineTest
[FAIL. Reason: OwnableUnauthorizedAccount(0x7FA9385bE102ac3EAc297483Dd6233D62b3e1496)] testRevertsIfTransferFromFails() (gas: 1600030)
Logs:
  Transferring ownership of DSC to DSC Engine
  DSC Engine deployed

Traces:
  [8972774] DscEngineTest::setUp()
    ├─ [4061538] → new DeployDsc@0x5615dEB798BB3E4dFa0139dFa1b3D433Cc23b72f
    │   └─ ← 20174 bytes of code
    ├─ [4704498] DeployDsc::run()
    │   ├─ [3001246] → new HelperConfig@0x104fBc016F4bb334D775a19E8A6510109AC63E00
    │   │   ├─ [0] VM::startBroadcast()
    │   │   │   └─ ← ()
    │   │   ├─ [372255] → new MockV3Aggregator@0x90193C961A926261B756D1E5bb255e67ff9498A1
    │   │   │   └─ ← 1082 bytes of code
    │   │   ├─ [372255] → new MockV3Aggregator@0xA8452Ec99ce0C64f20701dB7dD3abDb607c00496
    │   │   │   └─ ← 1082 bytes of code
    │   │   ├─ [449186] → new ERC20Mock@0xBb2180ebd78ce97360503434eD37fcf4a1Df61c3
    │   │   │   └─ ← 2018 bytes of code
    │   │   ├─ [449186] → new ERC20Mock@0xDB8cFf278adCCF9E9b5da745B44E754fC4EE3C76
    │   │   │   └─ ← 2018 bytes of code
    │   │   ├─ [0] VM::stopBroadcast()
    │   │   │   └─ ← ()
    │   │   └─ ← 5457 bytes of code
    │   ├─ [956] HelperConfig::activeNetworkConfig() [staticcall]
    │   │   └─ ← MockV3Aggregator: [0xA8452Ec99ce0C64f20701dB7dD3abDb607c00496], MockV3Aggregator: [0x90193C961A926261B756D1E5bb255e67ff9498A1], ERC20Mock: [0xDB8cFf278adCCF9E9b5da745B44E754fC4EE3C76], ERC20Mock: [0xBb2180ebd78ce97360503434eD37fcf4a1Df61c3], 77814517325470205911140941194401928579557062014761831930645393041380819009408 [7.781e76]
    │   ├─ [0] VM::startBroadcast(<pk>)
    │   │   └─ ← ()
    │   ├─ [591266] → new DecentralizedStableCoin@0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3
    │   │   ├─ emit OwnershipTransferred(previousOwner: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000, newOwner: 0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266)
    │   │   └─ ← 2609 bytes of code
    │   ├─ [868180] → new DscEngine@0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512
    │   │   └─ ← 3658 bytes of code
    │   ├─ [0] console::log("Transferring ownership of DSC to DSC Engine") [staticcall]
    │   │   └─ ← ()
    │   ├─ [2424] DecentralizedStableCoin::transferOwnership(DscEngine: [0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512])
    │   │   ├─ emit OwnershipTransferred(previousOwner: 0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266, newOwner: DscEngine: [0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512])
    │   │   └─ ← ()
    │   ├─ [0] VM::stopBroadcast()
    │   │   └─ ← ()
    │   ├─ [0] console::log("DSC Engine deployed") [staticcall]
    │   │   └─ ← ()
    │   └─ ← DecentralizedStableCoin: [0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3], DscEngine: [0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512], HelperConfig: [0x104fBc016F4bb334D775a19E8A6510109AC63E00]
    ├─ [956] HelperConfig::activeNetworkConfig() [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← MockV3Aggregator: [0xA8452Ec99ce0C64f20701dB7dD3abDb607c00496], MockV3Aggregator: [0x90193C961A926261B756D1E5bb255e67ff9498A1], ERC20Mock: [0xDB8cFf278adCCF9E9b5da745B44E754fC4EE3C76], ERC20Mock: [0xBb2180ebd78ce97360503434eD37fcf4a1Df61c3], 77814517325470205911140941194401928579557062014761831930645393041380819009408 [7.781e76]
    ├─ [46789] ERC20Mock::mint(USER: [0xF921F4FA82620d8D2589971798c51aeD0C02c81a], 100000000000000000000 [1e20])
    │   ├─ emit Transfer(from: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000, to: USER: [0xF921F4FA82620d8D2589971798c51aeD0C02c81a], value: 100000000000000000000 [1e20])
    │   └─ ← ()
    └─ ← ()

  [1600030] DscEngineTest::testRevertsIfTransferFromFails()
    ├─ [566640] → new MockFailedTransferFromErc20@0x2e234DAe75C793f67A35089C9d99245E1C58470b
    │   ├─ emit OwnershipTransferred(previousOwner: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000, newOwner: DefaultSender: [0x1804c8AB1F12E6bbf3894d4083f33e07309d1f38])
    │   └─ ← 2486 bytes of code
    ├─ [822851] → new DscEngine@0xF62849F9A0B5Bf2913b396098F7c7019b51A820a
    │   └─ ← 3658 bytes of code
    ├─ [46856] MockFailedTransferFromErc20::mint(USER: [0xF921F4FA82620d8D2589971798c51aeD0C02c81a], 10000000000000000000 [1e19])
    │   ├─ emit Transfer(from: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000, to: USER: [0xF921F4FA82620d8D2589971798c51aeD0C02c81a], value: 10000000000000000000 [1e19])
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [615] MockFailedTransferFromErc20::transferOwnership(DscEngine: [0xF62849F9A0B5Bf2913b396098F7c7019b51A820a])
    │   └─ ← OwnableUnauthorizedAccount(0x7FA9385bE102ac3EAc297483Dd6233D62b3e1496)
    └─ ← OwnableUnauthorizedAccount(0x7FA9385bE102ac3EAc297483Dd6233D62b3e1496)

Suite result: FAILED. 0 passed; 1 failed; 0 skipped; finished in 2.00ms (164.96µs CPU time)

Ran 1 test suite in 792.85ms (2.00ms CPU time): 0 tests passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped (1 total tests)

Failing tests:
Encountered 1 failing test in test/unit/DscEngineTest.t.sol:DscEngineTest
[FAIL. Reason: OwnableUnauthorizedAccount(0x7FA9385bE102ac3EAc297483Dd6233D62b3e1496)] testRevertsIfTransferFromFails() (gas: 1600030)

Encountered a total of 1 failing tests, 0 tests succeeded

        vm.prank(owner);
        mockDsc.transferOwnership(address(mockDsce));

    function testRevertsIfTransferFromFails() public {
        // Arrange - Setup
        address owner = msg.sender;
        vm.prank(owner);
        MockFailedTransferFromErc20 mockDsc = new MockFailedTransferFromErc20();
        tokenAddresses = [address(mockDsc)];
        feedAddresses = [ethUsdPriceFeed];
        vm.prank(owner);
        DscEngine mockDsce = new DscEngine(tokenAddresses, feedAddresses, address(mockDsc));
        mockDsc.mint(USER, AMOUNT_COLLATERAL);

        vm.prank(owner);
        mockDsc.transferOwnership(address(mockDsce));
        // Arrange - User
        vm.startPrank(USER);
        ERC20Mock(address(mockDsc)).approve(address(mockDsce), AMOUNT_COLLATERAL);
        // Act / Assert
        vm.expectRevert(DscEngine.DscEngine_CollateralTransferFailed.selector);
        mockDsce.depositCollateral(address(mockDsc), AMOUNT_COLLATERAL);
        vm.stopPrank();
    }



In order to transfer the ownership you must emulate the call from the actual owner. (As it wouldn't make sense to transfer the ownership to someone if you are not the owner)
vm.prank(address) enables you to make the next call from the specified address, owner in your case.
Keep in mind that when you are calling from foundry to a test the address that you use is address(this), not msg.sender.

vm.prank sets the msg.sender, however the vm.prank(msg.sender) doesn't make sense to me. TY
